# Metamask is not able to execute normal transactions in private quorum blockchain

Tags: metamask, quorum

I am setting up a quorum network with two nodes from the scratch which are using the RAFT consensus mechanism. The two nodes are live, up and running. One is specified as minter and the other is verifier. I have deployed a smart contract into the private quorum chain network using the Truffle framework.

I was able to add the contract token and account info to Metamask and retrieve corresponding ETH balance and token balances.
[image]

However, when I tried sending normal Ether between two accounts using Metamask (by using the accounts connected to Quorum chain), the transaction fails with the following message

[image]

[image]

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":6378119053557,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf88b17850af16b1600830f424094e8bd1fc300c3cd85bf033a13effe02226d22e76280a4c6ed8990000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a82f4f5a04e31045bf76c16a594ee742be05909019bfe31b0c57cca66918b13898b3684fda023aa10926436f4eec79d2a08407a55ba35d1dad4d50d9029dc26d7d7629bfabf"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} [object Object]
```

I have been trying to debug this error for a while but no success whatsoever. Requesting experts for help on this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happen with me sometime.I tried a lot of things but easy one is:-
Go to:-
**Setting > Advance >Reset** and reset account.

**Note:**-Resetting your account **will clear your transaction history**. This will not change the balances in your accounts or require you to re-enter your seed phrase.